# How to create grouped bars charts with matplotlib with data in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

This is my current output:
[image]
Now i want the next bars next to the already plotted bars.

My DataFrame has 3 columns: 'Block', 'Cluster', and 'District'.

'Block' and 'Cluster' contain the numbers for plotting and the grouping is based
on the strings in 'District'.

**How can I plot the other bars next to the existing bars?**

```
df=pd.read_csv("main_ds.csv")
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
bwidth=0.30
indic1=ax.bar(df["District"],df["Block"], width=bwidth, color='r')
indic2=ax.bar(df["District"],df["Cluster"], width=bwidth, color='b')
ax.autoscale(tight=False)

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        h = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*h, '%d'%int(h),
                ha='center', va='top')
autolabel(indic1)
autolabel(indic2)
plt.show()
```

Data:

District    Block   Cluster Villages    Schools Decadal_Growth_Rate Literacy_Rate   Male_Literacy   Female_Literacy Primary ... Govt_School Pvt_School  Govt_Sch_Rural  Pvt_School_Rural    Govt_Sch_Enroll Pvt_Sch_Enroll  Govt_Sch_Enroll_Rural   Pvt_Sch_Enroll_Rural    Govt_Sch_Teacher    Pvt_Sch_Teacher
0   Dimapur 5   30  278 494 23.2    85.4    88.1    82.5    147 ... 298 196 242 90  33478   57176   21444   18239   3701    3571
1   Kiphire 3   3   94  142 -58.4   73.1    76.5    70.4    71  ... 118 24  118 24  5947    7123    5947    7123    853 261
2   Kohima  5   5   121 290 22.7    85.6    89.3    81.6    128 ... 189 101 157 49  10116   26464   5976    8450    2068    2193
3   Longleng    2   2   37  113 -30.5   71.1    75.6    65.4    60  ... 90  23  90  23  3483    4005    3483    4005    830 293
4   Mon 5   5   139 309 -3.8    56.6    60.4    52.4    165 ... 231 78  219 58  18588   16578   17108   8665    1667    903
5 rows × 26 columns

Comment: is the upper picture your goal or your current output? If it is the goal: what is the outcome right now? Else: Do you want stacked bars?

Comment: the upper picture is my current output. I want the second bar stacked next to it...

Comment: ah ok, so grouped bar charts

Comment: another  thing is notice that the values of the bar isn't sitting nicely on top of the bar charts. It's all over the place...

Comment: what do you mean with 'District' is text. Is the content still a number but in string format?

Comment: The District column contains names of places...

Comment: So your goal is to have grouped bars and the height is given by 'Block' and 'Cluster', and the grouping is based on 'District'?

Comment: yup, so the Block and Cluster stacked together for each District...

Comment: i think the correct term is multiple bar chart as i want the bars lined up and not on top over it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using [pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def add_value_labels(ax, spacing=5):
    for rect in ax.patches:
        y_value = rect.get_height()
        x_value = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2

        space = spacing
        # Vertical alignment for positive values
        va = 'bottom'

        # If value of bar is negative: Place label below bar
        if y_value < 0:
            # Invert space to place label below
            space *= -1
            # Vertically align label at top
            va = 'top'

        # Use Y value as label and format number with one decimal place
        label = "{:.1f}".format(y_value)

        # Create annotation
        ax.annotate(
            label,                      # Use `label` as label
            (x_value, y_value),         # Place label at end of the bar
            xytext=(0, space),          # Vertically shift label by `space`
            textcoords="offset points", # Interpret `xytext` as offset in points
            ha='center',                # Horizontally center label
            va=va)                      # Vertically align label differently for
                                        # positive and negative values.

first3columns = StringIO("""District    Block   Cluster
Dimapur 5   30
Kiphire 3   3
Kohima  5   5
Longleng    2
Mon 5   5
""")

df_plot = pd.read_csv(first3columns, delim_whitespace=True)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()


#df_plot.set_index(['District'], inplace=True)
df_plot[['Block', 'Cluster']].plot.bar(ax=ax, color=['r', 'b'])
ax.set_xticklabels(df_plot['District'])

add_value_labels(ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Here, df_plot = pd.DataFrame({
    'District': [date(2020,8,19), date(2020,8,20), date(2020,8,21), date(2020,8,22)],
    'Block': [2,15,2,7],
    'Cluster': [0,2,11,0]
}) Can i do df["District"] instead as  i am reading it from a csv file?

Comment: @OchenAo You didn't give your data, so I generate some by my own to show how the plot looks like using my code. The logic of my code has nothing to do with the data.

Comment: @OchenAo Sure you can. You only need to replace my `df_plot` defination with `df_plot = pd.read_csv("main_ds.csv")`.

Comment: KeyError: "None of ['District'] are in the columns"

Comment: I update my answer to use your data. I have no idea why `District` is not in the columns. Could post the result of `print(df)`?

Comment: found out the problem, df_plot.set_index(['District'], inplace=True) is causing the District header name to disappear so i have commented that out and ran it. It's coming out nicely as expected however the District name is not being populated down at the bottom, it only displays  the index number

Comment: @OchenAo See my updated answer. I avoid to use `df_plot.set_index(['District'], inplace=True)`.

Comment: Great, much better now.... Will work on some few more stuffs

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
indic1=ax.bar(df["District"],df["Block"], width=bwidth, color='r')
indic2=ax.bar(df["District"],df["Cluster"], width=bwidth, color='b')
```

to

```
indic1=ax.bar(df["District"]-bwidth/2,df["Block"], width=bwidth, color='r')
indic2=ax.bar(df["District"]+bwidth/2,df["Cluster"], width=bwidth, color='b')
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't seem to be stacking next to it but rather over it..

Comment: And how do you see now? Please, provide some data to replicate it (print(df.head())).

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Comment: District Block Cluster Villages Schools Decadal_Growth_Rate Literacy_Rate Male_Literacy Female_Literacy Primary ... Govt_School Pvt_School Govt_Sch_Rural Pvt_School_Rural Govt_Sch_Enroll Pvt_Sch_Enroll Govt_Sch_Enroll_Rural Pvt_Sch_Enroll_Rural Govt_Sch_Teacher Pvt_Sch_Teacher
0 Dimapur 5 30 278 494 23.2 85.4 88.1 82.5 147 ... 298 196 242 90 33478 57176 21444 18239 3701 3571
1 Kiphire 3 3 94 142 -58.4 73.1 76.5 70.4 71 ... 118 24 118 24 5947 7123 5947 7123 853 261
2 Kohima 5 5 121 290 22.7 85.6 89.3 81.6 128 ... 189 101 157 49 10116 26464 5976 8450 2068 2193

Comment: df["District"] is a text string so you can't do a math operand on it, i suppose....